# Getting location updates for longitude and latitude values obtained from Geocoder

Tags: android

I have made a application which gets the details like area and city from database and with that details using geocoder i got the longitude and latitude values. Now I want to provide location updates with location providers after certain time. I could only get the solution using LocationManager. Kindly please provide me the solution, is it possible to get location updates as what i am expecting? and suggest me what i can do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I don't really understand what the issue is. You say you have the solution using LocationManager ... then what is the issue if you have the solution? Also please read [ask] to learn how to best formulate your questions! :)

Comment: i get latitude and longitude using Geocoder and with these I have set markers on the Overlay... my Question is How could I update longitude and latitude values? I have seen LocationManager example but I am unable to understand how to get location updates using location providers. Thats the issue for me. Sorry for inconvenience caused to u.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure how you want to update your location, by using Location API or by geting location from your db and converting it to longitude and latitude? In my way, I use the former one. So the code is sth like this:(make your app implementing `Observer`)

```
public class SFLocationManager extends Observable {

private static SFLocationManager lm;

private SFLocationManager(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public static SFLocationManager getInstance(Context context) {
    if(lm == null) {
        lm = new SFLocationManager(context);
    }
    return lm;
}

private static final int minTime = 1000 * 10 * 10;
private static final float minDistance = 20.0f;

private Context context;

private LocationManager mLocationManager;

private Location mCurrentBestLocation;

private String mLocationProvider;

public String getLocationProvider() {
    return mLocationProvider;
}

public void registerLocationListener() {
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean isWIFIEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if(isGPSEnabled) {
        mLocationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationProvider, minTime, minDistance, mLocationListener);
    } else if(!isGPSEnabled && isWIFIEnabled) {
        mLocationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationProvider, minTime, minDistance, mLocationListener);
    } else if(!isGPSEnabled && !isWIFIEnabled) {
        mLocationProvider = null;
    }
}

public void removeLocationListener() {
    if(mLocationManager != null) {
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
    }
}

private LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
         if (location != null) {
                if(LocationUtil.isBetterLocation(location, mCurrentBestLocation)) {
                    mCurrentBestLocation = location;
                    notifyObservers(location);
                }
         }
    }
};

public Location getBestLocation(String provider) {
    if(mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
    boolean isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean isWIFIEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if(!isGPSEnabled && !isWIFIEnabled) {
        return null;
    } else {
        if(provider != null) {
            Location lastKnownLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if(lastKnownLocation != null) {
                if(LocationUtil.isBetterLocation(lastKnownLocation, mCurrentBestLocation)) {
                    mCurrentBestLocation = lastKnownLocation;
                }
            }
            return mCurrentBestLocation;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

}


public class LocationUtil {

private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;

/** Determines whether one Location reading is better than the current Location fix
  * @param location  The new Location that you want to evaluate
  * @param currentBestLocation  The current Location fix, to which you want to compare the new one
  */
public static boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
    if (currentBestLocation == null) {
        // A new location is always better than no location
        return true;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
    long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
    boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

    // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
    // because the user has likely moved
    if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
        return true;
    // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
    } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
    int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
    boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
    boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
    boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

    // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
    boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
            currentBestLocation.getProvider());

    // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
    if (isMoreAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/** Checks whether two providers are the same */
private static boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
    if (provider1 == null) {
      return provider2 == null;
    }
    return provider1.equals(provider2);
}

public static boolean isLocationAvailable(Context context) {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean isWIFIEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    return isGPSEnabled || isWIFIEnabled;
}

}
```

Comment: I was able to successfully get the location details {longitude and latitude} using Geocoder from details of database. What i want now is how to get updates using location providers to these details so that it automatically set the markers to overlay with updated location?

Comment: the code above is exactly about how to register location listener and request updates.In your activity, do 

1. `SFLocationManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addObserver(this);` in `onCreate`

2. `SFLocationManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerLocationListener();` in `onStart`

3. `SFLocationManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerLocationListener();` in `onStop`

4. `SFLocationManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).deleteObserver(this);` in `onDestroy`

5. implements `Observer` in your `Activity`, then you will receive `Location` data in `update`